# How does IHOP calculated in G1 GC for starting concurrent marking cycle?

Tags: java, jvm, openjdk

I'm trying to understand how G1 GC calculates the marking threshold and how it uses the values of `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent` and `-XX:+G1UseAdaptiveIHOP` determine the marking threshold and with which occupancy percentage (old generation or entire heap) this marking threshold value will be compared.

Documentation says two different ways of calculations,

[First one](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111) says, the occupancy calculation is of the entire heap not any generation.

```
 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=percent
Sets the percentage of the heap occupancy (0 to 100) at which to start a concurrent GC cycle. It’s used by garbage collectors that trigger a concurrent GC cycle based on the occupancy of the entire heap, not just one of the generations (for example, the G1 garbage collector).
```

[Second one](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector.html#GUID-572C9203-AB27-46F1-9D33-42BA4F3C6BF3) says, threshold is the percentage of old generation size

```
The Initiating Heap Occupancy Percent (IHOP) is the threshold at which an Initial Mark collection is triggered and it is defined as a percentage of the old generation size.
```

It is not clear that,
`occupancy percent = (current old generation size/Current total Heap size)*100`

or

`occupancy percent = (Current Heap usage/Current total Heap size)*100`

Can someone point me to the right calculation here?

Answer (score 0):

Conclution First:

`occupancy percent = (current old generation usage + allocated bytes /Current total Heap size)*100`

Code is clearly in  src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1Policy.cpp of openjdk-jdk11u

```cpp
bool G1Policy::need_to_start_conc_mark(const char* source, size_t alloc_word_size) {
 ...
  size_t marking_initiating_used_threshold = _ihop_control->get_conc_mark_start_threshold();

  size_t cur_used_bytes = _g1h->non_young_capacity_bytes();
  size_t alloc_byte_size = alloc_word_size * HeapWordSize;
  size_t marking_request_bytes = cur_used_bytes + alloc_byte_size;

  bool result = false;
  if (marking_request_bytes > marking_initiating_used_threshold) {
    result = collector_state()->in_young_only_phase() && !collector_state()->in_young_gc_before_mixed();
   ...
  }

  return result;
}
```

Just old generation include humongous_set.

code in src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1CollectedHeap.hpp

```cpp
  size_t non_young_capacity_bytes() {
    return (_old_set.length() + _humongous_set.length()) * HeapRegion::GrainBytes;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

`(current old generation size/Current total Heap size)*100`
I have a jvm process with -Xmx12g -Xms12g -IHOP45%.
It trigger a YGC (not a mix gc) when Eden: 6.5G, Old:4.5G, Sur:8M.
4.5/12<45% (OK)

11g/12g>45% (should mix gc but not.)

Comment: Is this an answer, or noting that you're having the same or similar question/issue?

Comment: Yes, it's an answer.

Comment: Then can you edit it to make it more clear that this is an answer, please?